# when Electron renderer process request HTTPS API, initial connection (SSL negotiation ) is too slow - why?

Tags: node.js, ssl, electron

My service(AAA) works on Electron. It's a kind of chatting service.
We provide it as a web(BBB), too.

The AAA creates a renderer process with preload.js and loads the BBB by `loadURL(BrowserWindow)`. But `HTTPS` requests from BBB(inside AAA) take a long time on SSL negotiation.  Do you know the reason?
It happens on **some machine.. not every..**

And loading BBB by chrome, it takes short network time on the same machine.

[slow SSL capture image(chrome devtools)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uaB3.png)

when it happens, it occurs continuously even though reinstall..
But if, install by perMachine.. It happens no more....

repro version

```
"electron": "10.1.6",
"electron-builder": "22.9.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer...

It's related with anti-malware(anti-virus) program. As I turned off realtime protection of anti-malware, It ran fast as usual.

It looks like this [issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/1487) related.